# Custom migration not appearing in the migration UI

Tags: 7, migrations

I wrote a custom migration module, and I have enabled it in the Drupal 7 administration pages. I have searched through the web, but nothing shed any light on my issue. I came across [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1299912), but it was not helpful.

I have under sites/all/modules/my_module the following 4 files:

- my_module.info (contains the necessary info and included .module and .inc files)
- my_module.module (contains `my_migration_migrate_api()`)
- my_user_migration.inc (contains class MyMigration extends Migration)
- my_module.install (empty file by looking at online examples - http://btmash.com/article/2011-02-25/migrating-content-using-migrate-module)

I apologize, but I really don't know how I could be more specific with my question. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: For the purpose of importing users, I found it much easier to use the Feeds module.

Comment: As I had the same issue. Clearing the caches did not work, but try to disable and enable your custom migration module. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

Is your module enabled? (Seriously, my Drush Make file forgot to enable the module, and I was clueless, yesterday.)

If you use `drush migrate-status` from the command line, is your Migration listed?

Comment: tenken always to my rescue! when i type "drush migrate-status" in my var/www/drupal7 directory, it says the "drush command could not be found" ..this is frustrating. I have enabled migrate, migrate UI, migrate examples even...and if you are talking about the drush module, i could not even find it in my modules listing.

Comment: also to add, when i type "drush help" all the commands are listed, i see "drush migrate-status" and all the other migrate related drush commands. but when i type them, i get a command not found error.

Comment: I mentioned Drush because "migration" builds drush task for each Migration class you define. The UI is merely reading whatever drush sees and makes a UI to interact with it. I'm not sure how else to help you. You're positive your module is enabled? :)

Comment: tenken, i have gotten drush to recognize the sample beer and wine migrations (drush ms will reveal them). however, when i enable my own migration module, i get the following error: "PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate" would you be able to offer any insights?

Answer (score 0):

If you copied from the examples the info file has hidden = TRUE which makes it a hidden module.